# How do I inspect what CSS styles are applied to proprietary pseudo-elements in IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, pseudo-element, developer-tools

For example, `<select>`s have an [`::-ms-expand` pseudo-element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465742.aspx) in IE10+. Other such `-ms`-prefixed nonstandard pseudo-elements are listed on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As of writing this, they include: `::-ms-browse`, `::-ms-check`, `::-ms-clear`, `::-ms-expand`, `::-ms-fill`, `::-ms-fill-lower`, `::-ms-fill-upper`, `::-ms-reveal`, `::-ms-thumb`, `::-ms-ticks-after`, `::-ms-ticks-before`, `::-ms-tooltip`, `::-ms-track`, `::-ms-value`.

How can I inspect the CSS styles getting applied to these pseudo-elements in the F12 Developer Tools?

Comment: Same question, 3 years later...